# Can I produce the result of np.outer using np.dot?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to improve my understanding of numpy functions.  I understand the behaviour of `numpy.dot`. I'd like to understand the behaviour of `numpy.outer` in terms of `numpy.dot`.

Based on this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product I'd expect for array_equal to return True in the following code.  However it does not.

```
X = np.matrix([
    [1,5],
    [5,9],
    [4,1]
])

r1 = np.outer(X,X)
r2 = np.dot(X, X.T)
np.array_equal(r1, r2)
```

How can I assign r2 so that `np.array_equal` returns True?  Also, why does numpy's implementation of `np.outer` not match the definition of outer multiplication on Wikipedia?

Using numpy 1.9.2

Comment: Your understanding of the relationship between inner and dot/transpose seems correct.  What data are you using for `X`? I get True for simple vectors and arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the verification!  Just edited my question to include input data.

Comment: For me it still returns True

Comment: My mistake @DSM, I just removed the Y.

Comment: Use `np.array()` instead of `np.matrix...`.  `matrix` has its own matrix multiplication operator (`*`).  Things will be clearer if you stay away from `matrix`.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using @Hadrián?  I am using 1.9.2

Comment: You cannot write the outer product in terms of  np.dot for matrix, at least in an easy way. Outer product should not return a matrix, instead it should return some kind of 4 dimensions matrix. Numpy doesn't really do the outer (tensor9 product, what numpy does is to transform your matrix in a vector and them it makes the outer product of those vectors. An easier way to see how the outer product work is to use vectors instead of matrix. In that case your code will work

Comment: The outer product is defined on vectors, not matrices.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [303]: X=np.array([[1,5],[5,9],[4,1]])
In [304]: X
Out[304]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [5, 9],
       [4, 1]])
In [305]: np.inner(X,X)
Out[305]: 
array([[ 26,  50,   9],
       [ 50, 106,  29],
       [  9,  29,  17]])
In [306]: np.dot(X,X.T)
Out[306]: 
array([[ 26,  50,   9],
       [ 50, 106,  29],
       [  9,  29,  17]])
```

The Wiki outer link mostly talks about vectors, 1d arrays.  Your `X` is 2d.

```
In [310]: x=np.arange(3)
In [311]: np.outer(x,x)
Out[311]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
In [312]: np.inner(x,x)
Out[312]: 5
In [313]: np.dot(x,x)   # same as inner
Out[313]: 5
In [314]: x[:,None]*x[None,:]   # same as outer
Out[314]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
```

Notice that the Wiki outer does not involve summation.  Inner does, in this example `5` is the sum of the 3 diagonal values of the outer.

`dot` also involves summation - all the products followed summation along a specific axis.

Some of the wiki outer equations use explicit indices.  The `einsum` function can implement these calculations.

```
In [325]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',X,X)
Out[325]: 
array([[ 26,  50,   9],
       [ 50, 106,  29],
       [  9,  29,  17]])
In [326]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',X,X.T)
Out[326]: 
array([[ 26,  50,   9],
       [ 50, 106,  29],
       [  9,  29,  17]])
In [327]: np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,x)
Out[327]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
In [328]: np.einsum('i,i->',x,x)
Out[328]: 5
```

As mentioned in the comment, `np.outer` uses `ravel`, e.g.

```
return a.ravel()[:, newaxis]*b.ravel()[newaxis,:]
```

This the same broadcasted multiplication that I demonstrated earlier for `x`.

Comment: That is an interesting relationship to note.  I'm looking to understand outer though!

Comment: Are you asking about `np.outer(X,X)`?

Comment: @Selah `np.outer` just ravels n-dimensional arrays and then takes the conventional 1D outer product. N-dimensional `outer` isn't well defined.

Answer (score 3):

numpy.outer only works for 1-d vectors, not matrices. But for the case of 1-d vectors, there is a relation.

If

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
```

then this

```
np.matrix(A).T.dot(np.matrix(A))
```

should be the same as this

```
np.outer(A,A)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (clunky) version similar to `a[:,None] * a[None,:]`

```
a.reshape(a.size, 1) * a.reshape(1, a.size)
```